# Regular expression matches the pattern instead of minimum length instead of the desired maximum

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, text

The below code as an example returns `'ol'` when the objective was to return the word `'cool'`

```
import re
re.search( r'.*([a-z]{2,}).*', 'this is very cool').group(1)
```

That is, regex matched "at least 2 characters" and did not check if more could be matched. How to get regex to match the maximum possible number of characters instead of the minimum?

That is, how to achieve the output of `'cool'`?

Comment: You can use `r'\b(\w{2,})\s*$'` as regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `ol` is that the initial `.*`  in your pattern grabs the whole string at once, and then backtracking occurs to accommodate for the subsequent subpatterns. When `ol` is "freed" from the grabbed text, the `[a-z]{1,2}` matches that substring and the regex engine calls it a day and returns the match (the trailing `.*` is of no importance here).

You may use a word boundary to make sure the `.*` backtracks to the beginning of the last word that starts with 2 lowercase letters and may have more:

```
.*\b([a-z]{2,})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sxFpMS/1)

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZxgPLh):

```
import re
rx = r".*\b([a-z]{2,})"
s = "this is very cool"
m = re.search(rx, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
# => cool
```